# UITableView Delegate methods not getting called in UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopover

I have implemented `UIPopoverPresentationController` which contain `UITableView` and `UISwitch`. Everything working fine except `UITableView` Delegate methods not getting called. Deletgate method only called when i call `performSelector` like this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(reloadTblData) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0]
```

And `reloadTblData` is just an empty method. nothing i am doing there.
What could be the reason?

Comment: I guess delegate object is `nil`.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan how it is getting called by just writing performSelector line

Comment: From where are you calling your tableView delegate methods??

Comment: @VishalSonawane you can see i have a nib file where i am creating tableview and attach delegate and datasource and methods declared in the same class

Answer (score 2):

Check to see how you are retaining the delegate.

Delegates and datasources are weakly referenced, so if there isn't a View Controller holding a reference, they can be destroyed.

If the Table View is part of a View Controller that is also the delegate, there won't be an issue. But if the delegate is a separate object, it will be garbage collected at the end of the run loop.